# How to right-align any line or word in a paragraph in any documentclass?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have done some search for margin alignment in Latex but cannot find how can I right-align any single line?

For example, in a letter sometimes we put a Sincerely on the right. But without using specific documentclass, how can I align any single line in a paragraph to the right in any documentclass?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tested with `\rightline{text}`?

Comment: Have you looked into using `\raggedleft`?

Answer (score 88):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\hspace*{\fill} Yours sincerely

This is some more text

\null\hfill Yours sincerely

Again some dummy text

\hspace*{0pt}\hfill Yours sincerely

And again Phew

\mbox{}\hfill Yours sincerely
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The way you write your answer might induce the idea that `\par` is necessary. I'd simply propose the `<blank line> \hspace*{\fill} <text>` solution.

Comment: @egreg Oh! Sorry. I wanted it to be a new line and I preferred `\par` over `\\\`  I changed it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify which of these options is the most appropriate in various situations? Or are they all identical?

Answer (score 41):

For a *short* line  (With lenght less than `\linewidth`) you can use `\rightline{word or phrase}`.

If you want to align a paragraph at right put it in a `flushright` environment. This way allows line breaks with `\\`.

```
\begin{flushright}
Text\\
aligned to\\
the right.
\end{flushright}
```

Answer (score 12):

The simpler solution to right align a line is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Here comes some text.
Have a nice day.

\rightline{Yours sincerely}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a neat solution (thanks!). I wonder why it has not gotten many upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

This will work if the right-aligned content is considered a separate paragraph (i.e., it will have `\parskip` separation).  Note that it will have less vertical separation than a `flushright` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
{\raggedleft Sincerely,\par}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```