# How to move the label up or down on the next line in a enumerate/itemize list?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I want to create a custom listing/structured display for some data that is enumerated (in my case a list of [FOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information) requests.

This is a MWE I've already created with `enumitem` mostly:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}


% description with better font
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textsf{#1}}
% better right align
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195775/98645
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Titel}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=2em,font=\vspace{-2em}\normalsize]
            \item
            % left
            {\small
%               \hphantom{\normalsize\textsc{An:\,}}
                \textsf{Anfrage nach dem IFG}
                % right
                {\hspace*{\fill}\textsf{
                        Az.: J-0123/00/42
                        $\cdot$
                        Nummer: \#133742%
            }}}
            \vspace{1pt}
            \\
            \textsc{An:} {\large Bundesbeauftragter für den Datenschutz und die Informationsfreiheit}
            \begin{description}[
                    labelindent=0em,
                    leftmargin=10.5em,
                    style=multiline,
                    itemsep=1pt,
                    parsep=1pt,
                    labelsep=1em,
                    align=parright
                ]
                
                \item [Anfragedatum:]
                8. Juni 2020
                \item [Anfragetext:]
                Anfrage an Datenschutzbehörde\\
                {\small (ohne Anfrage nach Datenschutzverletzungen nach Art.~33 DSGVO)}
                \item [Adresse:]
                \texttt{https://fragdenstaat.de/anfrage/…}
                \item [Status:]
                Bearbeitung ausstehend
                \item [Antwortdatum:]
                -
                \item [Ergebnis:]
                -
            \end{description}
            \item
            % left
            {\small
    %               \hphantom{\normalsize\textsc{An:\,}}
                \textsf{Anfrage nach dem Informationsfreiheitsgesetz}
                % right
                {\hspace*{\fill}\textsf{
                        Nummer: \#ABC123%
            }}}
            \vspace{1pt}
            \\
            \textsc{An:} {\large Bundesbeauftragter für Anderes} \\
            …
        \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the result]

---

The only problem I still have is the “label“, i.e. I want to *move that down* one *line*, i.e. it should be shown *before* the `\textsc{An:}` as if the first line would not exist.
The reason is just that the first line is purely “cosmetic” and should not influence where the bzu.
What I've already accomplished is resetting the font to the normal size for that bullet point/list item.

Please make your answer *agnostic* of whether I use `enumerate` or `itemize` or so there, because possibly I'd change that later.

I've also [checked the usual spacings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300512/98645), but I can as far as I see I can only move the whole item, not the label/bullet point alone.

But as these are likely the same settings in `enumitem` or so, I guess that is not hard.

So, **how can I move the label/bullet point/number down or up?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}


% description with better font
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textsf{#1}}
% better right align
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195775/98645
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\newcommand\loweritemlabel[1]{\normalsize\raisebox{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-1pt}[0pt][0pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{Titel}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=2em,format=\loweritemlabel]
            \item
            % left
            {\small
%               \hphantom{\normalsize\textsc{An:\,}}
                \textsf{Anfrage nach dem IFG}
                % right
                {\hspace*{\fill}\textsf{
                        Az.: J-0123/00/42
                        $\cdot$
                        Nummer: \#133742%
            }}}
            \vspace{1pt}
            \\
            \textsc{An:} {\large Bundesbeauftragter für den Datenschutz und die Informationsfreiheit}
            \begin{description}[
                    labelindent=0em,
                    leftmargin=10.5em,
                    style=multiline,
                    itemsep=1pt,
                    parsep=1pt,
                    labelsep=1em,
                    align=parright
                ]

                \item [Anfragedatum:]
                8. Juni 2020
                \item [Anfragetext:]
                Anfrage an Datenschutzbehörde\\
                {\small (ohne Anfrage nach Datenschutzverletzungen nach Art.~33 DSGVO)}
                \item [Adresse:]
                \texttt{https://fragdenstaat.de/anfrage/…}
                \item [Status:]
                Bearbeitung ausstehend
                \item [Antwortdatum:]
                -
                \item [Ergebnis:]
                -
            \end{description}
            \item
            % left
            {\small
    %               \hphantom{\normalsize\textsc{An:\,}}
                \textsf{Anfrage nach dem Informationsfreiheitsgesetz}
                % right
                {\hspace*{\fill}\textsf{
                        Nummer: \#ABC123%
            }}}
            \vspace{1pt}
            \\
            \textsc{An:} {\large Bundesbeauftragter für Anderes} \\
            …
        \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and code helps very much, but AFAIK it's best practice on Stackexchange also to write at least one or two sentences of what exactly you know changed in the code and how that does work, so people can learn from that.

Comment: E.g. how can I adjust that if I change the font size. If I replace `\normalsize` with `\large` in `\loweritemlabel` it does not fit anymore.

Comment: sorry I looked at it shortly and offered a solution, but I don't have the time to write an article about it.