# The Location of the Date in Letter Class

Tags: vertical-alignment, letters, date

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\begin{letter}
{Name \\ 
Address \\ 
Location } 

%\date{February 15, 2023}

\opening{Dear ---,} 

 \lipsum[3]
  
\closing{Sincerely yours,\\[2pt]Me} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

I would like to vertically reposition the date so that it lies (right justified) between "Location" and "Dear---". How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\opening[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\toname \\
      \toaddress \\[\parskip]
      \hspace*{\fill}\@date % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195781/273733
      \par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
  {\raggedright}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{letter}
{Name \\ 
Address \\ 
Location } 

%\date{February 15, 2023}

\opening{Dear ---,} 

 \lipsum[3]
  
\closing{Sincerely yours,\\[2pt]Me} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```